# Configure shop information Error during Installation

Tags: prestashop

in ubuntu14.04 while I am installing PrestaShop in the last step in Configure Shop information I face an error & The Error is :

*ERROR*         2014/07/05 - 07:38:45: Current theme unselected. Please check your theme configuration. at line 100 in file config/config.inc.php

PLZ help . thanks in advance

nginx , MariaDB , php-fpm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. that was because of replication in mysql.

```
auto_increment_offset=1     
auto_increment_increment=2
```

so it can not create it's table's row's inorder.   `1,2,3,4,5,6,...`